# USA Today-like iPad Multipage Column Layout

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, html

I'm trying to achieve a layout like this: http://www.ipadinsight.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/LakersWin.jpg to be a multi-page multi-column layout working on one body of text. Any ideas? I think that CSS can handle the multi-layout question, but not the paging. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is for a website not an app, right? I see you have included the objective-c tag... Do you have any code yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using css property like webkit-column-count, css example below.

```
div
{
    -moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
    column-count:3;
}​
```

Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/Bqjcc/

Comment: You are right, thank you, but the problem here is that the longer the text the longer the columns will be, they will never span to another page, which's exactly what want. Imagine how annoying would it be for a user to keep going up and down to read a block of text.

Comment: displaying text in multi column can be done as mentioned above, splitting and displaying long text content can be done via script either utilizing javascript or mostly via server side scripting. Paging text can't be done via css directly.

Answer (score 0):

How about a grid system?

I prefer the 1140 css grid: http://cssgrid.net/

The 960 grid is also popular: http://960.gs/